# Image saved in preferences is not loading picture onCreate method

Tags: android

I have implemented an uploading of image and it does upload an image but after activity is ***closed*** it is not picking the saved image in **preferences**(*picturepath*)

I have used **Glide** to upload an image so please try to tell in that context and used ***circle transform*** as a frame to upload my image into this frame.

***My activity class :***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    EditText pname;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    ImageView profimg;
    String picturePath;

    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp=getSharedPreferences("profilePicture",MODE_PRIVATE);



        profimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimg);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        displayView(0);
        pname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pname);

        profimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        pname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pname.setInputType(0x0000006);
                pname.setCursorVisible(true);

            }
        });
        pname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if(hasFocus){
                        pname.setCursorVisible(false);
                    }
                else{
                        pname.setCursorVisible(false);
                    }
            }
        });


        pname.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event!=null && event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || actionId != EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ) {
                    return false;
                }
                else if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event==null || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                        pname.setCursorVisible(false);
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(pname.getWindowToken(), 0);
                          return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(sp.getString("dp" ,"").equals(picturePath)){
            Glide.with(this).load(picturePath)
                    .crossFade()
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profimg);
        }

    }



    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Glide.with(this).load(picturePath)
                    .crossFade()
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profimg);

            sp.edit().putString("dp", picturePath).apply();


        }
    }
```

Comment: `the saved image in preferences`. ??? How does one save an image in preferences? And why?

Comment: @greenapps No not image I am using glide to upload an image but you can see I have passed picture path before uploading  and this path I am saving in my preferences and in onCreate method I am checking if there is "dp" which is actually picturepath of an image uploaded before then set it using glide. I hope you get it.

Comment: @greenapps Can you resolve it or you didn't get anything ?

Comment: @greenapps I guess I am missing the checking of preferences part in here but still I tried not working can you tell me how to check it ????

Comment: @greenapps and why because after I restart my app this profile picture is no more there but I want it permanent until I change it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my Own Problem at Last here is the answer to it.

First declare **globally**:  `SharedPreferences sp;`

Now in onCreate method do this :

```
sp=getSharedPreferences("profilePicture",MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean path =sp.contains("dp");

 if(path) {
            String value=sp.getString("dp",picturePath);
            Glide.with(this).load(value)
                    .crossFade()
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profimg);
        }
```

in onActivityResult do this after loading picture with glide

```
sp.edit().putString("dp", picturePath).apply();
```

This will save your image everytime you upload a new image and restart your app this image will be there until you upload another one and so it goes like that.

Comment: @greenapps hmmm....My profile image was not able to restore or you can say the image which i upload i can't see that image when i close and start my app again....So what I did is save that image path using saved preferences which I uploaded the first time and in onCreate using this same preferences I am uploading the the same picture, and if you still didn't got that please look my question and then answer then also if you didn't get it. Buddy I can't help you. Thank you for your time. ;)

Comment: A lot of words but you still did not explain what you did do wrong before.

Comment: @greenapps I can't see my uploaded image when I start my app again I told you please look man

Comment: Yes that we know already a long time. You solved that already. Great! But you keep repeating yourself while just telling what you did wrong before still lacks.

Comment: @greenapps OK I guess please you should look the code I didn't know how to check with shared preferences in onCreate method I didn't put that code because It was wrong and then added some more logic at last it worked by doing some changes like that boolean path variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130202/discussion-between-sameerkhan1406-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps Apart from this atleast you got to know how to save image in preferences(saving picturepath), well i mentioned this bracket hint above but I guess you overlooked it.

Comment: `please you should look the code`. No. I asked you to tell us what you changed. To tell why it did not work before. `you got to know how to save image in preferences`. My god you stiil talk about an image instead of an image path. Don't put things between brackets which are essential.

Comment: @greenapps common everyone know what can be saved in preferences I was talking about image path only but you misinterpret things here. Obviously I was talking about path of an image if you would know you would've given an answer straight away but instead you were shocked and you were like "This can be done and you also asked why"? now every now and then do I have to give an explanation briefly. All I asked was how to get the image again without doing that uploading again like in other profile picture app example whatsapp ...can't believe I need to explain you so much

Comment: @greenapps OK enough said and asked I am discussing uselessly answer this then I'll know you were right I misunderstood and should elaborate more before asking. If you are smart enough answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059922/version-issue-in-glide-library-to-upload-an-image-android