# Version Issue in glide library to upload an Image Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I have uploaded an image using ***glide library*** it's working fine under version below **lollypop** but it seems that mobile above that version doesn't upload an image because as soon as I upload an image the default image just ***vanish and replaced*** with nothing just ***blank*** 
My default image [image: Default Image]
So as after **uploading** anything from anywhere it just gives blank nothing and in my other mobile whose version is **KitKat** working absolutely fine

This is glide library version I am using : **`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`**

```
// Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused maybe because **storage permission** need to be handled at runtime.
In my Case I Have to `Handle WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.